# Pytorch load model

Tags: conv-neural-network, pytorch

I used tensorflow some days ago. To build conv layers with fixed weights is easy, just pass the weight kernel to `conv2d()`. And it is convenient to load pretrained models such as `VGG19`. But I found it did't work that way using pytorch, because `conv2d()` doesn't accept an explicit kernel but a kernel size. So I wonder if there is any possibility that we can reuse the weights in `VGG19` by simply passing it to a method like `conv2d()`. Any reply will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I can see that you have 2 questions . How to use a pre-trained model like VGG in pyTorch and how to set the weights for a particular layer like nn.conv2d().

For creating a pretrained Vgg model you can use the below code.

```
from torchvision import models    
model_vgg = models.vgg16(pretrained=True)
for param in model_vgg.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False
```

In PyTorch you implement neural network subclassing nn.Module which contains the parameters() function which returns all the weights associated with the network.

Setting the weights of a particular layer .

```
decoder = nn.Linear(10, 100) 
decoder.weight = #Do anything which is valid.
```

You can check my code [here](https://github.com/svishnu88/pytorch/blob/master/TransferLearning.ipynb) to know more on how to use a trained model.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: If it helped you , you can choose it as the answer.